# Can i access ember service variables in my whole application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I Created an ember service and i initialized its value now i updated that value in a controller. I want this updated variable in my complete application ? What should i supposed to do. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you read the [Services section](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/) of guides? If you managed to create a service, inject it into a controller and set a variable of that service in the controller, reading a variable in another place should be straight forward. Maybe it would be helpful if you include the code used for the steps you already managed.

Comment: Yes i read that but my question is a bit different if i have a routes named login and i updated the service in that login route and i want to access this updated service in another controller of route for example posts route

Comment: Service state is app-level, so if anything changes in any service, the whole app can view the changes

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Can You please post an example code. That will be really appreciated i am able to see that changes with in the controller and children controllers but unable to get in app level.

Comment: As far as examples, I just have these: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/emberclear/tree/master/packages/frontend

Comment: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/emberconf-2019

Comment: But they use experimental features

Answer (score 2):

Just dummy example

- Service

```
// header.js

import Service from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
  currentRoute: null
});
```

- Route

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { set } from '@ember/object';

export default Route.extend({
  header: service(),

  beforeModel() {
    set(this, 'header.currentRoute', 'login');
  }
});
```

- Any controller

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed, get } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
  header: service(),

  currentRoute: computed('header.currentRoute', function() {
    return get(this, 'header.currentRoute');
  })
});
```

I hope you understood the idea

Comment: I think your setter won't set a value to the service `property`. you must call a service `method` to update the value of service property and access it globally throughout the app.

Comment: You don't need `get` anymore if using Ember >= 3.1. Your example is a little bit strange cause you have [RouterService which provides a `currentRoute` property](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.8/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRoute?anchor=currentRoute).

Comment: @jelhan It's just a DUMMY, just provide the idea

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this article from the ember guide https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/#toc_invoking-actions-directly-on-component-collaborators

You did the correct thing, once you already set an updated value of that variable in your service that value will be the same until you instructed your code to change the value of that variable. To answer your question, `Can i access ember service variables in my whole application?` Yes you can, you can do the following to access the variable into your application.

Assuming that this is your variable and service name
//services/current-session.js

```
import Service from '@ember/service';


export default Service.extend({
  foo: 'foo bar baz',
});
```

If you want to access it in your `controller` please do the following

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as injectService } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
  currentSession: injectService(),

  bar: computed('currentSession.foo', function() {
    return this.currentSession.foo;
  }),
});
```

If you want to access it in your component

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as injectService } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  currentSession: injectService(),

  bar: computed('currentSession.foo', function() {
    return this.currentSession.foo;
  }),
});
```

The approach above is based on ember-cli `3.4` Here's an ember-twiddle you can play around. https://ember-twiddle.com/b92a7d4fa03a1699a5b8a79aca5d2782?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

If you want to change the value of your variable in your service through your controller you can do this

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { set } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as injectService } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
  currentSession: injectService(),

  actions: {
    change() {
      this.currentSession.set('foo', 'foo bar baz please');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You `can not` change the value of a `service property` from your `controller`. Please look at your own `twiddle`. That doesn't work.

Comment: @rinoldsimon This is simply wrong. You can mutate a property of an injected service. There is nothing wrong with it. There is no need for a special setter function. Even so the code example has some other issue. Especially computed property `bar` is not recomputed if `foo` property of `currentSession` service changes due to wrong dependency key.

Comment: @jelhan you mean this `this.currentSession.set('foo', 'foo bar baz please');` works ?

Comment: @rinold simon the main question was if the variable from the service can be used? Yes it can be use anywhere, the example above was only to show how to use the variable on the application or how to change the application. The value of the computed property may change if we observe any changes of a variable. Thus, I did not show it because the question is how to use the service in a application.

Comment: If you want to see if the value of a variable from the service do a console log right after the set to see if the foo value changed

Comment: Observer should use if we want to recompute the bar computed property

Comment: @rinoldsimon Please find an Ember Twiddle demonstrating that the code in this answer works here: https://ember-twiddle.com/73733849f3fcd5f75aa63f3ee85a27e5?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C `this.currentSession.set('foo', value)` works even so I would recommend `this.set('currentSession.foo', value)` for readability. You could also do `set(this, 'currentSession.foo', value)` but that's harder to understand IMO and there is no need for it as a Service is an EmberObject by definition.

Comment: @Mikelemuel There is no need for an observer. The depend key of computed property should reflect the variable and not only the service. `computed('currentSession', function() {})` is only invalidated if `currentSession` changes but not if property `foo` of the `currentSession` service changes. You need to put the exact property to do so: `computed('currentSession.foo, function() {})` [Tracked properties](https://blog.emberjs.com/2019/02/26/coming-soon-in-ember-octane-part-3.html) will remove that complexity.

Comment: You right, I guess I missed that. Thank you for pointing that out but then I really hope that the person who asked the question got our point hehe.

Comment: Updated the twiddle changed the `computed('currentSession', function() {})` to `computed('currentSession.foo', function() {})`

Answer (score -1):

working [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/#/c4c29c7a758e97e74480801009bd3247).

Steps:

1) create a service:

`app/services/service-name.js`

```
import Service from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
  name: "hello",
  changeName(name) {
    this.set('name', name);
  }
});
```

2) Create an initializer so you need not to inject the service in every route/controller/component.

`app/initializers/inject-service-name.js`

```
export function initialize(application) {
  application.inject('controller', 'serviceName', 'service:service-name');
  // if needed
  // application.inject('route', 'serviceName', 'service:service-name');
  // application.inject('component', 'serviceName', 'service:service-name');
}

export default {
  initialize
};
```

once initializer is created kindly `restart` your ember server.

3) Usage:

`app/controller/application.js`

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    // print initial value
    console.log(this.get('serviceName').name); // hello
    // change value of name property in service
    this.get('serviceName').changeName("hai");
    // print changed value
    console.log(this.get('serviceName').name); // hai
  }
});
```

Comment: There is no need to inject the service in an initializer. Instead this makes reading the code way more difficult as you don't see the value of `serviceName` in controller. IMO this is an antipattern.

Comment: since the question was like - the service variable is to be used at `multiple places` in the application. Though i suggested using initializers